# How do I make an AIML bot respond with sound? And is there a way to make this sound a custom voice?

Tags: audio, text, bots, speech, aiml

I am making an AIML bot, but I don't want it to be only text-based conversations. I want the bot to respond with a voice that ideally I created myself.

Comment: You can give a voice to your bot by using a TTS service like www.cereproc.com or Amazon Polly. Cereproc offer a bespoke voice service but I doubt it comes cheap!

Answer (score 0):

If you use aiml in a java application for example. You can add a sound in java when the answer shows.
In pandora there is no such thing